# How to change AWS Cognito app name from Google Login?

Tags: amazon-cognito, google-signin

The name of my app inside Google Login using AWS Cognito is "amazoncognito.com". How can I change this? (Javascript sdk)

Ex: [image]

Comment: Were you able to change the name? If yes, can you clarify how to do so? I tried creating a custom domain but still it didn't change the app name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a custom domain for your user pool. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html